# perform / trigger segue only after data is saved via parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a strange problem where the user inputs some data through a text box clicks ok, the IBAction function does this.

```
@IBAction func savedata(sender: AnyObject) {
    var query = PFQuery(className:"xxxx")
    ....
    ....
    parseObj.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if success {
       println("Object Saved")
    } else {
       println("Error")
    }
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueX", sender: self)
}
```

I want to make sure that this data is completely saved before the segue is performed. I tried having that function in prepareForSegue, but noted that the object is not saved till few secs after the next view controller is presented, as a result querying for the object in the next view controller viewdidload returns no results.

I also tried dispatch_async to save it, but without success. Not sure if this is a parse related question or iOS, but any suggestions would be helpful.

The solution is to add retries to the queries till results are returned in the target view controller, but I would like a much better solution for this.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have above? As long as the 'performSegueWithIdentifier(...)' is within the callback block, it should perform the segue AFTER the save's been completed

Comment: No it doesn't, that's why I was puzzled. I got a solution few secs back that told me to add the performSegueWithIdentifier within the success block (not sure it's you, but it got removed), that solution works perfectly fine and I would have accepted that response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing a `}` and I am therefore unsure where the `performSegue` actually is placed. It **should** be placed in the callback - you might even want to move it in the `success` case to be able to do some error handling or resending or anything in the `fail` case:

```
@IBAction func savedata(sender: AnyObject) {
    ...
    parseObj.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if success {
            println("Object Saved")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueX", sender: self)
        } else {
            println("Error")
            // retry !? do something appropriate
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, you want to save THEN perform the segue, however you're using the function incorrectly. According to the documentation: https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#saveInBackground(com.parse.SaveCallback). 'saveInBackground' is a asynchronous function, so you need to call 'performSegueWithIdentifier' from within the callback block to ensure the segue is done AFTER the object's been saved.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it if you save in `prepareForSegue` then `performSegue` will be called